# Entrez.efetch returns incomplete genbank records

Tags: genbank, entrez, efetch

I am using the biopython Entrez.efetch command to retrieve all features (CDS, mRNA, ...) of some genomes.

In this case (NC_014649, Acanthamoeba polyphaga mimivirus), it works as expected:

```
from Bio import Entrez, SeqIO
handle = Entrez.efetch(id='NC_014649', db='nuccore', rettype='gb')
records = SeqIO.read(handle, 'gb')
records.features

[SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(0), ExactPosition(1181549), strand=1), type='source'),
 SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(191), ExactPosition(2609), strand=1), type='gene'),
 SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(191), ExactPosition(2609), strand=1), type='mRNA'),
 SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(191), ExactPosition(2579), strand=1), type='CDS'),
...
```

However in this case (NC_010830, Candidatus Amoebophilus asiaticus), it only returns one record for the whole genome.

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(id='NC_010830', db='nuccore', rettype='gb')
records = SeqIO.read(handle, 'gb')
records.features
[SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(0), ExactPosition(1884364), strand=1), type='source')]
```

However, if I check the corresponding file in the browser, it does have features: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_010830.1

What could be the reason for this inconsistency ? Did I  miss something ?

Comment: This happens and when I've encountered this I resolved it by digging the features out by a different method, @arijeman 'solution' if correct needs an explanation about why because it's funndamental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been answered before. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55402322/6262370

In short, you need to either use `rettype='gbwithparts'` or `rettype='gb', style='withparts'` to download the entire genbank flat file.

Comment: Thanks, I also had to set `retmode='full'`, otherwise `SeqIO.read` would result in "ValueError: No records found in handle"

Answer (score 0):

I use the `efetch` bash command from **edirect**.

With `efetch -db nuccore -id CP001102.1 -format gb`, I get the *Candidatus Amoebophilus asiaticus 5a2*, complete genome in **GenBank format**.

You might try your command with `CP001102.1` instead of `NC_010830`